# Concise way to retrieve a row from a Polars DataFrame with an iterator of column-value pairs

Tags: python, indexing, python-polars, composite-key

I often need to retrieve a row from a Polars DataFrame given a collection of column values, like I might use a composite key in a database. This is possible in Polars using `DataFrame.row`, but the resulting expression is very verbose:

```py
row_index = {'treatment': 'red', 'batch': 'C', 'unit': 76}

row = df.row(by_predicate=(
    (pl.col('treatment') == row_index['treatment'])
    & (pl.col('batch') == row_index['batch'])
    & (pl.col('unit') == row_index['unit'])
))
```

The most succinct method I've found is

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

expr = reduce(and_, (pl.col(k) == v for k, v in row_index.items()))

row = df.row(by_predicate=expr)
```

But that is still verbose and hard to read. Is there an easier way? Possibly a built-in Polars functionality I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(a == b) & (c == d)` will return true if all of the conditions are true.

Another way to express this is with [`pl.all_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal)

```py
pl.all_horizontal(a == b, c == d)
```

- [`pl.any_horizontal()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html#polars.any_horizontal) can be used for "logical OR"

To which you can pass your comprehension directly:

```py
expr = pl.all_horizontal(
    pl.col(k) == v for k, v in row_index.items()
)

df.row(by_predicate=expr)
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you for the quick response. Though, since my question specifically mentions `DataFrame.row`, could you include an example with that method as well, to make clear `pl.all` also works with it? To avoid confusion for any future readers.

Comment: @Etherian I've expanded a bit on the answer - feel free to edit it if you think it needs improving.

Comment: Perfection! Thank you for such a thorough answer.